# Find lat & lng from a marker, with autocomplete search box

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>GLANCE</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

  <style>
    html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    #map {
      height: 70%;
    }
    .controls {
      margin-top: 10px;
      border: 1px solid transparent;
      border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
      height: 32px;
      outline: none;
      box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    }
    #pac-input {
      background-color: #000000;
      font-family: Roboto;
      font-size: 15px;
      font-weight: 300;
      margin-left: 12px;
      padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
      width: 300px;
    }
    #pac-input:focus {
      border-color: #4d90fe;
    }
    .pac-container {
      font-family: Roboto;
    }
    #type-selector {
      color: #000000;
      background-color: #4d90fe;
      padding: 5px 11px 0px 11px;
    }
    #type-selector label {
      font-family: Roboto;
      font-size: 13px;
      font-weight: 300;
    }
    #target {
      width: 345px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Digita Località">
  <div id="map"></div>
  <script>
    // This example adds a search box to a map, using the Google Place Autocomplete
     // feature. People can enter geographical searches. The search box will return a
     // pick list containing a mix of places and predicted search terms.

     // This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
     // parameter when you first load the API. For example:
     // <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">
    var marker;
    var xlat;
    var xlon;

    function initAutocomplete() {
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {
          lat: 44.689205,
          lng: 10.663778
        },
        zoom: 14,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      });
      if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
          initialLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
          map.setCenter(initialLocation);
          xlat = position.coords.latitude;
          xlon = position.coords.longitude;

          marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png',
            map: map,
            draggable: true,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            position: {
              lat: position.coords.latitude,
              lng: position.coords.longitude
            }

          });
          marker.addListener('click', toggleBounce);
        });


      }

      // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
      var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
      var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
      map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

      // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
      map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
        searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
      });


      var markers = [];
      // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
      // more details for that place.
      searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
        var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

        if (places.length == 0) {
          return;
        }

        // Clear out the old markers.
        markers.forEach(function(marker) {
          marker.setMap(null);
        });
        markers = [];

        // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        places.forEach(function(place) {


          var icon = {
            url: place.icon,
            size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
            origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
            anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
            scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
          };

          // Create a marker for each place.
          markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            draggable: true,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            position: place.geometry.location
              // var xlat = place.geometry.location.lat();
              // var xlon = place.geometry.location.lon();
          }));




          if (place.geometry.viewport) {
            // Only geocodes have viewport.
            bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
          } else {
            bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
          }
        });
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
      });
    }


    function vai() {
      window.location = "listadomande.jsp?lat=" + xlat + "&lon=" + xlon;
    }
  </script>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDho6YqRH605Poc-S0AcShQu4hLYDUMGpk&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete" async defer></script>
  <footer id="footer">

    <br>
    <ul class="actions">
      <li>
        <p onclick="vai()" class="button big">INVIA</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </footer>

</body>

</html>
```

I succeed to find the coordinates of the initial point that I've named xlat & xlon (geolocalized), but I don't know how to change this xlat and xlon when I search another place. I tried with xlat = place.geometry.location.lat();       xlon = place.geometry.location.lon(); But when I put these the map disappear =(
[Link to the map page](https://1-dot-glance-1294.appspot.com/mappa.html)

```
`var marker;
   var xlat;
   var xlon;
      function initAutocomplete() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: 44.689205, lng: 10.663778},
          zoom: 14,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
                initialLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
                map.setCenter(initialLocation);
                xlat = position.coords.latitude;
                xlon = position.coords.longitude;

                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png',
                    map: map,
                    draggable: true,
                    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                    position: {lat: position.coords.latitude, lng: position.coords.longitude}

                });
                  marker.addListener('click', toggleBounce);
            });


            }

        // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
        var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
        var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

        // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
        map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
          searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
        });


        var markers = [];
        // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
        // more details for that place.
        searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
          var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

          if (places.length == 0) {
            return;
          }

          // Clear out the old markers.
          markers.forEach(function(marker) {
            marker.setMap(null);
          });
          markers = [];

          // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
          var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
          places.forEach(function(place) {


            var icon = {
              url: place.icon,
              size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
              origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
              anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
              scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
            };

            // Create a marker for each place.
            markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                draggable: true,
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                position: place.geometry.location
           **xlat = place.geometry.location.lat();
             xlon = place.geometry.location.lon();**
            }));




            if (place.geometry.viewport) {
              // Only geocodes have viewport.
              bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
            } else {
              bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
            }
          });
          map.fitBounds(bounds);
        });
 }


    function go(){
        window.location="get.jsp?lat="+xlat+"&lon="+xlon;
    }`
```

Comment: Can you please create fiddle for this?

Comment: @NiketanRaval I put the snippet and also the link to the page under the description of the problem... Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I think what may be a solution here is not to set xlat and xlong as variables within the Javascript code but to include them as hidden elements on the page and set the values when you return the latitude and longitude. So, for example, in your html code, place something like this

```
<div id="xlat" data-attr-val="" ></div>
<div id="xlong" data-attr-val="" ></div>
```

Then when you return the longitude and latitude values, you can replace these lines

```
**xlat = place.geometry.location.lat();
 xlon = place.geometry.location.lon();**
```

with:

```
document.getElementById('xlat').setAttribute("data-attr-val", place.geometry.location.lat());
document.getElementById('xlong').setAttribute("data-attr-val", place.geometry.location.lon());
```

Then when you want to call the function vai() you could use this

```
function vai() {
    lat = document.getElementById('xlat').getAttribute("data-attr-val");
    lng = document.getElementById('xlng').getAttribute("data-attr-val");
    window.location = "listadomande.jsp?lat=" + lat + "&lon=" + lng;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it still disappear when I use `document.getElementById('xlat').setAttribute("data-attr-val",place.geometry.location.lat()); document.getElementById('xlong').setAttribute("data-attr-val", place.geometry.location.lon());` Inside the creation of the marker, I think that maybe I have to put it somewhere else, but don't know where ..

Comment: Can you see if the attributes have been set correctly?

Comment: for the initial location yes, but the search box doesn't work when I use that 2 lines inside ` markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({...}))` So I can't check if the attributes have the correct values...

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues with this code. Please look at this part:

`markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            draggable: true,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            position: place.geometry.location
               var xlat = place.geometry.location.lat();
               var xlon = place.geometry.location.lon();
 }));`

1. You try to define variables xlat and xlon inside the object that you pass as marker options. You should put these variables outside of the object.
2. Also, you have defined variables xlat and xlon outside of the initAutocomplete() function, so there is no need to use `var` again.
3. LatLng class of Maps JavaSript API doesn't have `lon()` method, it has `lng()` method: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en#LatLng

So your code should be

`markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            draggable: true,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            position: place.geometry.location
 }));
 xlat = place.geometry.location.lat();
 xlon = place.geometry.location.lng();`

You can see modified version at http://jsbin.com/nojima/edit?html,output